# Strange characters 'black square # ' or '??#' in Command Prompt , Powershell and VS Code Terminal

Tags: powershell, cmd, terminal, windows-10

Strange characters ' # '  or '??#' in Command Prompt , Powershell and VS Code Terminal. Commands don't run because of this. How to fix?
[image]

Comment: Q: Did you recently spill coffee on your keyboard?

Comment: does that happen every time you open a new console?

Comment: What language is set? It may appear at the right end of the task bar. You can change it by pressing the _Win_ key and space bar together. It needs to be English.

Comment: How do those symbols appear here ? You press `Win+R` -> `CMD.EXE`, and what's next ?

Comment: Yes, it happens every time I open the cmd. No, I did not spill coffee on keyboard.  It does not depend on which language is selected. When I uncheck "Beta. Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Region Settings and restart, the two question marks become a square.